# Exchange data between computer and android phone over Wifi

Tags: android

I have just started doing some Android development. One of the things that I would like to add to the app the I'm working on, is data exchange between a desktop computer and an android phone. Think of it like syncing data between Microsoft Outlook and the phone when it is connected to the wifi network. (Stanza on the iPhone is another good example)

The application that is running on the desktop is written in C# (to make it more interesting ;-)). I'm trying to avoid using a WebService, since this requires something like IIS.

Are there any libraries that can help me with this, or is it simple enough to do using the Java Socket functionalities?

Answer (score 1):

I'd still find a .NET alternative for [HttpSever](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html) and implement a simple RESTful (HTTP + JSON) protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You can try for socket programming. I am doing a project in which m data sending data from android activity and java class in desktop computer through sockets...